# ngTagsInput Tags dynamic and static angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, tags

I using `ngTagsInput` for [here](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/)

and I would like to create a filed like that - that holds tags when tags the user can enter by himself (dynamic) and some his can choose from a list (static)
so let say I have a list of tag that contains : happy, sad, in love
when I user wants to tag he can write the letter **h** - he cause see happy in a drop down list but he does not have to choose it. he can write a new tag lets say for the example: hungry(static tag).

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the documentation in the link you have already provided. 
All you need to do is concatenate an array of your static and dynamic tag options and pass it to the `tags-input` directive.

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags"></tags-input>
```

Comment: I give this example but it doesnt work for me, can you explain what should I do?